# How do I change labels for a dropdown in a Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that asks the user to choose an origin and destination from a drop down. However, the labels are not what I want them to be. I would like to change this.

**Models.py:**

```
class locations(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    location = models.TextField()

class drones(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey('locations', models.PROTECT, null=True, related_name='destination_id')
    destination = models.ForeignKey('locations', models.PROTECT, null=True, related_name='origin_id')
```

**Views.py:**

```
def book(request):
    form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, '../../drone_system/templates/drone_system/book.html', context)
```

**Book.html:**

```
{% extends "drone_system/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <nav class="mx-auto card w-25" style=text-align:center;border:none;padding-top:12%>
        <form action="book" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            <h3 style="padding-bottom: 10px">Book</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <label for="Origin">Origin</label>
                    {{ form.origin }}
                    <br>
                    <label for="Destination">Destination</label>
                    {{ form.destination }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Book</button>
        </form>
    </nav>
{% endblock %}
```

**Forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import drones


class BookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = drones
        fields = ['origin', 'destination']
        widgets = {
            'origin': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'my-1 mr-2',
                },
                choices=((1, 'London'), (2, 'Plymouth'), (3, 'Swansea'), (4, 'Birmingham'), (5, 'Manchester'), (6, 'Edinburgh'), (7, 'Belfast'))
            ),
            'destination': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'my-1 mr-2',
                },
                choices=((1, 'London'), (2, 'Plymouth'), (3, 'Swansea'), (4, 'Birmingham'), (5, 'Manchester'), (6, 'Edinburgh'), (7, 'Belfast'))
            )
        }
```

As you can see, this comes out as follows:
[locations object(1), locations object(2)...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQUuX.png)

I instead want to see names of cities like London , Plymouth etc. These names are part of the locations model as well(locations.location). I have also tried using choices in forms.py, but it hasn't changed anything. How should I change this to city names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `__str__` in the model so it has a string representation

```
class locations(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

class drones(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.destination.location
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer. It has solved my problem and I will accept this as the answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me. I just had a couple questions, that might help my understanding. Why do I need a dunder string method? Why doesn't it work without it and how does it solve the problem? It would be great if you could answer these.

Comment: A model has many attributes (id, name, date...etc) and django does not now which field to display so it shows a default representation of the object, just like the one in the image. It's up to you to override `__str__` and specify which field will be displayed.